# No handles with labels found to put in legend. what is this error?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import pandas as pd

data3=pd.read_csv(r'10.7 and res.csv')

data=np.array(data3)

x=np.linspace(0,20,1023)

plt.plot(x,data[:,0],label='Ihh') plt.plot(x,data[:,1],label='Ihv') plt.plot(x,data[:,2],label='Ivh') plt.plot(x,data[:,3],label='Ivv') plt.plot(x,data[:,4],label='Response funtion') plt.figure(figsize=(10,6)) plt.xlabel('Time in ns') plt.ylabel('No of count') plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

Comment: why not put plt.figure before plt.plot so figure first plots next

Answer (score 0):

Just put the legend labels in a list as the first argument to the `plt.legend` method. This should work:

```
data3=pd.read_csv(r'10.7 and res.csv')

data=np.array(data3)

x=np.linspace(0,20,1023)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6)) 

plt.plot(x,data[:,0],label='Ihh') 
plt.plot(x,data[:,1],label='Ihv') 
plt.plot(x,data[:,2],label='Ivh') 
plt.plot(x,data[:,3],label='Ivv') 
plt.plot(x,data[:,4],label='Response funtion') 

plt.xlabel('Time in ns') 
plt.ylabel('No of count') 

plt.legend(['legend label #1', 'legend label #2', 'legend label #3', 'legend label #4', 'legend label #5'], loc='upper right')
```

or create a handles, as shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html), as follows:

```
data3=pd.read_csv(r'10.7 and res.csv')

data=np.array(data3)

x=np.linspace(0,20,1023)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6)) 

line1, = plt.plot(x,data[:,0],label='Ihh') 
line2, = plt.plot(x,data[:,1],label='Ihv') 
line3, = plt.plot(x,data[:,2],label='Ivh') 
line4, = plt.plot(x,data[:,3],label='Ivv') 
line5, = plt.plot(x,data[:,4],label='Response funtion') 

plt.xlabel('Time in ns') 
plt.ylabel('No of count') 

handles = [line1, line2, line3, line4, line5]

plt.legend(handles, loc='upper right')
```

Cheers